# Reading/Writing - Text File Or PostGres, please read more

Tags: java, mysql, file, postgresql, performance

I have approached you today to try and gather your opinions and experience with speed related to reading from the internet with Java. First of all, please let me explain my situation so you have a better understanding as to why I asked this question.

I can't say too much due to legal things regarding my business that I shall be running soon but I will do my best to cover the main point(s). Basically, I have a program that runs off that users can contribute towards online. ( I already I have a working version of this program in another programming langauge but I need to rewrite the program in Java ) The program I have accesses the online data and then writes it too a file for offline use! The data is stored in a MySQL database, currently, but if I was going too keep this method of accessing the data I would have to switch to Postgres. Hopefully you have enough information about what my program does for me now to go on to explaining my options;

**Option 1 - A  Database**

For this method I would be using the Postgres JDBC driver in the same way I accesed the data in my other program with MySQL. ( Postgres because of licensing issues with MySQL ) How I use it is simple, read a value then write a line containing the value to the file, until the end of the database is reached!

**Option 2 - Plain Text File**

This will work in a similar way to option 1, the only difference is a  would be working with a standard old '.txt' file. I thought this method may be a bit simpler and easier considering I have no experience with Postgres, but that is not the main thing I want to focus on. For this option I would have two methods ( if this option sounds best please could you tell me which method would be best ), I could either download the text and read it on the computer to re write it how I need it or read straight from the internet ( in that case I may use a HTML file instead of a TXT file )! Either way I would process the data just like in option 1.

**What I need to focus on**

Okay, now you know just about everything, there just one more final bit of information i need to tell you; and that is the main points I would like to focus on... And they are:

Speed - How long will it take to get the information and process it?

Simplicity - How easy will this be to code in Java for me, and,

Security - This is more the online factor where people can contribute, I don't mind people like seeing a document with contributions in but I don't want people to see a password or anything!

I think that's about it now, so if you guys have got any comments or advice, etc they will all be highly appriciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll touch only on speed/simplicity. I don't quite understood your security-related requirements :)

- Speed:
  ** if you refer to the speed of resource download from Internet, this will be the same. It doesn't depend on whether you store resource to filesystem or database.
  ** if you refer to the speed of storing resource than most probably storing to file will be faster than storing to database. But consider simplicity -- see below;
- Simplicity:
  ** Sequential reading/writing via filesystem is more simple than database access. However, this holds until you need to perform random-access access to stored resources, like writing resource after 1st resource but before 3rd, or reading resource based on some criteria. For these options SQL is better suited.

Comment: thank you for your answer! The security related question was the least important anyway, it was a bit pointless too - I realised after writting it that it may not have made the greatest sense :) Anyway, thanks for you advice/opinion it's helped me go towards an answer. I think I'm going to chose a filesystem for what I need to do!